# 'if there is anything in weight' meaning from the Hobbit

Tags: meaning

The quote if from The Hobbit by Tolkien, page 127:

> You have stacked some full casks here instead of the empty ones, **if there is anything in weight**.

What does it mean 'if there is anything in weight'?

Some context: Bilbo put dwarves inside empty casks and elves noticed the difference in weight. But what does an elf meant by 'if there is anything in weight'?

Comment: "If the difference in weight is of any significance."

Comment: Kate Bunting, oh, I get it now. Thank you!